# How to swap more than two variables using temporary variables

Tags: java, temporary-objects

I'm trying to figure out how to swap more than two variables around using a temp variable.  There are 4 variables to be swapped, 1,2,3 and 4.  Variable one is to swap with 2, 2 with 3, 3 with 4 and 4 with 1.  It seems simple enough but I've only learnt how to swap two variables so and am struggling with the larger scale.  I've tried

```
temp = 1
1 = 2
temp = 2 
2 = 3 
temp = 3
3 = 4
temp = 4
4 = 1
```

Do i need more than one temp variable?  Still only a beginner any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Sorry, forgot to add I'm coding for java.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an array along with a loop and one temporary variable will be enough. P-code since you didn't mention the language:

```
array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
tmp = array[0]
for i in [0, array.count - 1)
    array[i] = array[i + 1]
array[array.count - 1] = tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens in the third step. The original value of `1` (which was saved to `temp` in the first line) is lost, because you overwrite `temp` with the value of `2`.

As it turns out, there is no need to save a copy of the original value of `2` because there is already a copy in `1`. The same applies to all the other variables (except `1`).

So the only time you need to use `temp` is at the very start to save the value of `1` (like you are currently doing), and also at the very end when you assign the original value of `1` to `4`. You can't use `1` because it was overwritten, but a copy was saved in `temp` just for this purpose.

So the final code looks like this:

```
temp = 1
1 = 2
2 = 3 
3 = 4
4 = temp
```

Answer (score 1):

An array is a better approach for your requirement . In your present pseudo code , you can do something like this :

```
temp = 1
1 = 2
2 = 3 
3 = 4
4 = temp
```

In java , you can do something like below using array :

```
int[] x = {5,15,25,35};
int temporary = x[0];
for(int j=0;j<x.length-1;j++){
    x[j]=x[j+1];
}
x[x.length-1]=temporary;
```